# Prove that the coefficients of an interpolant polynomial has certain form

Tags: polynomials, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have a set of data $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=0,1,...n$.

I want to prove that if $p(x)=a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ then $\displaystyle a_n = \sum_{i=0}^n y_i \prod_{j=0,j\neq i}^n \frac{1}{x_i-x_j}$.

My attempt is that if $\displaystyle p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n y_i L_i(x)$ then $p(x_j)=y_jL_j(x_j)=y_j \delta_{j,j}=y_j=a_n x_j^n + a_{n-1}x_j^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$, so we can form the following matrix:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^n
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0\\
a_1\\
\vdots\\
a_n
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y_0\\
y_1\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
From here I don't know how to proceed. I know that I can get $a_i$ from Cramer's rule as:
\begin{equation}
a_i = \frac{\det{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_0 & \cdots & y_0 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_0 & \cdots & y_1 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & x_0 & \cdots & y_n & \cdots & x_0^n \\
\end{pmatrix}}}{\det{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_0^n \\
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^n
\end{pmatrix}}}
\end{equation}
The determinant from the denominator resembles the one from the Vandermonde's Matrix, but the one from the numerator I don't know how to calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My attempt is that if $\displaystyle p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n y_i L_i(x)$ then $\;\ldots$

That looks like the [Lagrange form of the interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Definition), in which case $\,\displaystyle L_i(x)= \prod_{j=0, \; j \ne i}^n \frac{x - x_j}{x_i-x_j}\,$.

The coefficient of $\,x^n\,$ in $\,L_i(x)\,$ is $\,\displaystyle b_i = \prod_{j=0, \; j \ne i}^n \frac{1}{x_i-x_j}\,$ and $\,\displaystyle \,a_n = \sum_{i=0}^n y_i b_i\,$ which gives the result.

Comment: Yes, I was totally confused with what the question asked. I thought I had to find $a_i$ for any $i\in\{0,1,...,n\}$. That's more interesting.

Comment: @math4everyone All $a_i$'s don't necessarily have simple closed forms, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472567/closed-form-solution-of-prod-i-1i-neq-jn-x-i) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997348/calculating-coefficients-of-interpolating-polynomial-using-nevilles-algorithm) for example.